# Parallel process csvs in python

Tags: python, csv

I have this code which reads a field from the top row of a csv
and writes it into a new column

it then saves out the csv ignoring the first and third rows which are no longer needed.

The problem is I have 50,000+ csvs to process.
Is it possible to parallel this so that it runs faster?
I need to do this a few times and it's a bit too slow.

```
import glob
import csv
import os

path = '/in/'
out = '/out/'

for fname in glob.glob(path):
    with open(fname) as csv_open:
        print j
        raw_name = os.path.basename(fname)
        outname = os.path.join(out, raw_name)

        reader = csv.reader(csv_open)

        all_t = []            
        row0 = reader.next()
        train = row0[0]

        row1 = reader.next()
        row1.append('Loco')
        all_t.append(row1)

        reader.next()

        for i, row in enumerate(reader):
            row.append(train)
            all_t.append(row)

        with open(outname, 'w') as csv_out:
            write_func = csv.writer(csv_out, lineterminator='\n')
            write_func.writerows(all_t)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely spawn several threads/processes to run that task in parallel. Have a look at (note I am assuming you are using Python 2 for your `print j` statement):

- [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)
- [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html)

Note however that Python's `threading` might [not behave as you would expect](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). So perhaps `multiprocessing` is what you are looking for: create a handful of processes and pass them the file names using a `multiprocessing.Queue` (keep the processes alive and pass them multiple file names instead of creating a new process for each new file).

Also, your bottleneck might be in the system's I/O throughput (meaning that the slowest part might be reading and writing those CSVs). In that case, parallelization won't really help much.

You could also try to optimize your code (or perhaps use another module or even programming language that might accelerate the processing). But I do not think this is the most worthy step to spend your time on.

I would go first for the multiprocessing until adding more processes does not improve performance (something that may happen sooner than later if the bottleneck is you system's I/O throughput). Then I would perhaps try to optimize the processing code a bit. Then if it is still very slow, I would just be patient and wait for the script to finish execution while I keep doing my work.